# pjax adding URL when selecting link

Tags: pjax

When I click on the first link pjax fires with the correct content. However, when I select the second link pjax adds to the alread select link like this "http://localhost.com/name/test1/name/test2/" then returns to the index page. I am guessing because of the addition of the second link. How do I resolve this problem?

```
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="name/test1/"> test1 </a></li>
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="name/test2/">  test2</a></li>
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="name/test3/">  test3 </a></li>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(function(){

  $('a[data-pjax]').pjax({container:'#content',timeout:15000});
   });

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I solved this my adding a forward slash "/" in front of all the "href" like this "href="/name/test1". for some reason it was causing a dub of the same url without it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are using relative path in the links, try changing it to:

```
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="/name/test1/"> test1 </a></li>
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="/name/test2/">  test2</a></li>
 <li><a data-pjax='#content' href="/name/test3/">  test3 </a></li>
```

By adding `/` at the beginning of your `href` attributes.

Assuming you started at `/`, when you click on the first link, pjax changes the page location `windows.location` to `/name/test1/`. A link to `name/test2/` on page `/name/test1/` means `/name/test1/` + `name/test2/` => `/name/test1/name/test2/`, since it is a relative path.